# Facebook SDK: How to upload photos on Facebook in Xcode

Tags: objective-c

I'm new in Objective C programming and I am starting to develop some applications. I am looking for a useful library to upload my Facebook photos. I am using updated version of Xcode with 5.1 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used in my application:

```
- (void)uploadImage:(UIImage *)image withName:(NSString *)name
{
    if (image)
    {
        incomingRequests++;
        //Image settings/parameters
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       name,@"caption",image, @"picture",
                                       nil];

        //method to upload images
        [self.facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"
                                   andParams:params
                               andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                 andDelegate:self];

        NSString *tempRequestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"photoUpload"];
        self.facebook.request_string = tempRequestString;
        [tempRequestString release];
    }
}
```

Refer this tutorial for a better understanding : [How To Use Facebook’s New Graph API from your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app) .